# How to calculate the positioning angle of a rocket for launch

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, drag, aerodynamics, rocket-science

I am building a model rocket. I want it to end up in a specific position. If I am taking into account the acceleration, starting position, end position, mass, and wind speed, how do I find the angle I have to point the rocket at in order to make it end up in that specific position?

Edit: Let me try to put this into perspective by using a 3D coordinate graph. Let's say that the rocket is starting at (0, 0, 0). I want the rocket to go to (0, 0, 1000). The problem is that there is air drag in a certain direction. I want to point the rocket angled towards the wind, so that the rocket travels in a parboliv shape that ends up at the point (0, 0, 1000). T

Comment: Can you describe your requirements in greater detail? 
When you say "end up", do you want the turning point to be at a specific point?

Comment: Air drag is the messy part.

Comment: Are you asking about a real rocket or a computer simulated rocket? If it is a real rocket do you have the apparatus to measure rocket thrust, wind speed and direction? How does thrust vary with time? Is the wind speed and direction constant? If you don't know these things it is pointless making an exact calculation. For real model rockets this is an **engineering problem** because there are many uncertainties. You need to make a rough guess to start then adjust whatever parameters you can (fuel mass, launch angles) until you get it right.